# Generating a client URL in a Timer running in global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 2 app that has a System.Timers.Timer object starting up during Application_Start in global.asax.  One of the things this timer needs to do is generate a daily e-mail to users when they have an item to review in their work queue.  Inside the e-mail is a link back to the item to review.

In code I have running in various controller actions, I use code like this to generate URLs that can be e-mailed to users:

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
builder.Path = Url.RouteUrl("ReviewDetails", new { id = reviewId });
return builder.ToString();
```

I would like to do the same inside my Timer's elapsed method in global.asax, but there is no HttpContext at that point, so I'm not able to programatically determine the URL.

I think the only solution is to store the site's root (ex: http://intranet.domain.com/MyApp) in the web.config and then use that to build the URL, like this:

```
string url = string.Concat(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteRoot"], "/Review/", reviewId.ToString());
```

I'm putting this out in the cloud to see if there are any better solutions to programatically genererating a URL for the client when the HttpContext is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the url in the Application_Start method and store it in the ApplicationState collection.

Comment: Yep, works perfectly.    protected void Application_Start()
  {
   _siteUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
  }

Comment: You should be able to access without the HttpContext.Current part. The request object is directly accessible within Application_Start

Answer (score 0):

There is always an HttpContext.  Try the `HttpContext.Current` static method.